# How to override value of TeamCity System Variable Using MSBuild?

Tags: msbuild, teamcity

**TeamCity Configuration:** 
Below is the Build Number format setting done in TeamCity
%system.BuildVersion%

Where BuildVersion is defined as system parameter.

**MSBuildScript**

```
<GetAssemblyIdentity 
AssemblyFiles="$(PPTCompiledOutputDirPath)\$(FileNameForAssembly)">
        <Output TaskParameter="Assemblies" ItemName="AssemblyIdentity"/>
    </GetAssemblyIdentity>
    <PropertyGroup>
        <Pattern>(\d+)\.(\d+)\.(\d+)\.</Pattern>
        <In>%(AssemblyIdentity.Version)</In>
        <OutVersion>$([System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex]::Match($(In), $(Pattern)))</OutVersion>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <Message Text="$(OutVersion)" />
    <Message Text="##teamcity[buildNumber '$(OutVersion)$(BuildCounter)']" />
    <Message Text="##teamcity[setParameter name='BuildVersion' value='$(OutVersion)$(BuildCounter)']"/>
```

I want to update the value for parameter 'BuildVersion' as Assembly Version and Build Counter.

Here I am getting the issue on execution of the Teamcity and execution get cancelled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proper way to set the buildNumber is:

```
<Message Importance="High" Text="##teamcity[buildNumber '$(OutVersion)$(BuildCounter)']" />
```